# Convert a column into multi column by groups

Tags: r

I have a data frame(df):

```
group col
a     12
a     15
a     13
b     21
b     23
```

Desired output is also a data frame(df1):

```
col1  col2
12    21
15    23
13    0
```

Namley, I want to partition "col" of "df" by "group" into multi columns as "col1" and "col2".

When the length of each column is not equal to each other, "0" must be added end of each column untill the length of each column reaches to the maximum column length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could either use `base R` functions `split` or `unstack` to split the 'col' by 'group' into a list, then pad `NA` to list elements that are less than the maximum length of the list element.  Change the column names, replace 'NA' by 0.

```
  lst <- unstack(df1, col~group)
  d1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(lst, `length<-`, max(sapply(lst, length))))
  d1[is.na(d1)] <- 0
  colnames(d1) <- paste0('col', 1:ncol(d1))
  d1
 #  col1 col2
 #1   12   21
 #2   15   23
 #3   13    0
```

Or use `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
d1 <- as.data.frame(stri_list2matrix(unstack(df1, col~group),
            fill=0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d1[] <- lapply(d1, as.numeric)
```

Or using `data.table/splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
setnames(dcast(getanID(df1, 'group'), .id~group, value.var='col',
             fill=0L)[, .id:= NULL], paste0('col', 1:2))[]
#    col1 col2
#1:   12   21
#2:   15   23
#3:   13    0
```

Answer (score 4):

How to do it with dplyr...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  spread(group, col) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  (function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x })
```

Comment: I was working on a similar solution but used   `mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))` to replace the NAs.

Comment: Of course! It looks even more elegant. On the other hand - subsetting is slightly faster than ifelse ...

Answer (score 3):

Since you fill with zeroes, another idea:

```
xtabs(col ~ ave(DF$col, DF$group, FUN = seq_along) + group, DF)
#                                      group
#ave(DF$col, DF$group, FUN = seq_along)  a  b
#                                     1 12 21
#                                     2 15 23
#                                     3 13  0
```

Where "DF":

```
DF = structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), col = c(12L, 15L, 13L, 21L, 23L)), .Names = c("group", 
"col"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```